Oauth2 redirect URI is using the wrong account
hoping some can help me.
I am using Oauth to authenticate users using their google credentials to grant access to an emmbeded iframe of LookerStudio in my web. Everything is working fine except, when a certain user has a second google account active, then the redirect URI logs the user with the incorrect account.

The user personal google account mail1@gmail.com is actively logged in, as the user visits their gmail account daily.
The user should use a specific account when logging in my web  mail2@gmail.com. My web requires an specific account, to ensure privacy of the users.
The user gets login prompt with the different google accounts that have been stored in their browser recently. The user as expected logs with mail2@gmail.com succesfully and is redirected to the corresponding page with the iframe, looker loads correctly. However looker shows everything as it was logged in as mail1@gmail.com.
In other words, the redirect uri does not take the oauth user logged in (mail2@gmail.com), but the previous logged in user in the browser (mail1@gmail.com).

My code:
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>

            <div id="g_id_onload"
                data-client_id="MY-CLIENT_ID"
                data-context="use"
                data-ux_mode="redirect"
                data-nonce=""
                data-prompt="select_account consent"
                data-login_uri="MY-REDIRECT-URI"
                data-itp_support="true"
                data-auto_prompt="false">
            </div>

            <div class="g_id_signin"
                data-type="standard"
                data-shape="rectangular"
                data-theme="outline"
                data-text="signin"
                data-size="large"
                data-locale="en-GB"
                data-logo_alignment="center"
                data-width="400">
            </div>


I have tried using different browsers, different computers. It replicates. The only way I found is log out before everything or use a private browsing window. Both are not user friendly.
I have searched forums but I cant find similar situations, which brings me to the conclussion I am doing something wrong, as I understand this should be a relatively common situation.
I expect to be able to understand what I am doing wrong, and hopefully be able to specify the URI to use the correctly ouath logged in account, instead of the previously account logged in the browser.
Note both accounts happen to exist in my app or my redirect URI permissions. That can be avoided, but the problem would persist. For example if mail@gmail.com would not exist in my app, but is taken as the active account, the redirect URI, or the looker iframe do block access for them as that account would not have access (tested).
Thanks in advance!

Anybody could please help?
